# Given $A\in Tn(R)$ show thast A is a scalar matrix if $e_{ij}=Ar_{ij}$, where $a\le i\le j\le n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Given $A\in Tn(R)$ show thast A is a scalar matrix if $e_{ij}=Ar_{ij}$, where $a\le i\le j\le n$

Prove for $1: e_{ii}A=Ae_{ii}$

and for

$2: e_{ij}A=Ae_{ij}$ where $i\le j$

Now for 1, I understand that if we are multiplying A by $e_{ii}$, whether it is from the left or the from the right, $e_{ii}$ is the one element, same row same column, with 0's everywhere else so the multiplication will produce a scalar matri and for 2, it will produce a matrix with only one non-zero element at $E_{ij}$ with 0's everywhere else. I'm just not sure how to quite prove this. My notation skills need a lot of help.

Comment: What is $Tn(R)$ (set of $n\times n$ matrices?), $e_{ij}$, $r_{ij}$, and $a$?

Comment: It's the set off upper triangular matrix rings

Comment: This question I have comes from an article [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959390141A). I just need help understanding it.

Comment: Ok, so $T_n(R)$ is a ring of upper triangular matrices over a ring $R$. Now it remains to specify what $e_{ij}$, $r_{ij}$, and $a$ would be. In addition, it would be nice to specify how the scalar matrix is defined (for some $\alpha\in R$, $Ax=\alpha x$ for all $x\in R^n$?).